# How to improve perfomance of a java program?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a Calc Runner java class .In this class process 6000 recrods,each record have some calculation takes 5-6 days to process the all records.How to improve the code with multi threading Thanks in advance

Comment: Without a code we can't help you.

Comment: me the approach how to do it

Comment: Use some profiler like jvisualvm  and find out the methods that take most of the time. Then try to ask a question including the relevant code.

Comment: you have to provide code for improve performance of your code

Comment: Take a look at the [Java concurrent programming documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/121/concurrent-programming-threads#t=201608310928215129129) on the new Documentation section of SO. There's some good examples on how to make your application multi-threaded there.

Comment: Start by reading the Oracle Java Tutorial section on Concurrency: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Answer (score 2):

There are several solutions to your problem. 
One of them is to use the Fork/Join framework.
Here is an example, just to show you how it works.

Of course it is just an example, which you can customize to your needs; in real life, no one would use the Fork/Join framework just to double values in an array.

Say you have an array of ints (sourceArray), and you want to fill another array (targetArray) with all the values of sourceArray doubled.
You can create a RecursiveAction, which contains your logic in the compute() method. The compute method can decide to compute the values itself, if the batch size is small enough, or can create two other smaller tasks to which delegate the computation.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;

public class ForkJoinPoolExample {

    public static final int ARRAY_SIZE = 6000;
    public static int[] sourceArray = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];
    public static int[] targetArray = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];

    public void initArray() {
        for (int i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
            sourceArray[i] = i;
        }
    }

    public static class Calc extends RecursiveAction {
        private int from;
        private int to;
        public static final int BATCH_SIZE=5;

        public Calc(int from, int to) {
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
        }

        @Override
        protected void compute() {
            if (to-from <= BATCH_SIZE) {

                for (int i = from; i<to; i++) {
                    targetArray[i] = sourceArray[i] * 2;
                }

            } else {

                 int middle = from +((to - from)/2);
                 invokeAll(new Calc(from, middle), new Calc(middle, to));
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ForkJoinPoolExample fjpe = new ForkJoinPoolExample();
        fjpe.initArray();
        ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
        ForkJoinTask task = new Calc(0, ARRAY_SIZE);
        pool.invoke(task);
        for (int i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
            System.out.println(sourceArray[i] + " -> " + targetArray[i]);
        }
    }

}
```